# cannot get scrollspy to work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am hving some issues getting bootstrap's scrollspy to work. The output page is generating fine without any javascript errors.

But when scrolling I just cant get the CSS class to apply the active.

Below is the JSFiddle I've setup.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/475sT/15/

```
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper" data-spy="scroll" data-target="main-navigation">
        <section class="container">
            <header id="header">
                <div id="sticky_navigation" class="shadow">
                    <div class="container"> <a href="/" id="logo"></a>

                        <div id="navigation-wrapper">
                            <nav id="main-navigation">
                                <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION-->
                                <ul id="main-menu">
                                    <li><a id="one" href="#one">One</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a id="Two" href="#Two">Two</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a id="Three" href="#Three">Three</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </section>
        <section id="one">One</section>
        <section id="two">Two</section>
        <section id="three">Three</section>
    </div>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Scrollspy not working with Affix and Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526728/bootstrap-3-scrollspy-not-working-with-affix-and-panel)

Answer (score 0):

Call the scrollspy via JavaScript:

```
$('#main-navigation').scrollspy()
```

By http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Comment: sorry for the delay response. I have tried, but nothing is happening.