# Bootstrap 3 Scrollspy not working with Affix and Panel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I'm trying to apply the bootstrap ScrollSpy to my affix navbar. There's something I'm missing because I think I've done everything right.

Here's my code:

```
        <script type='text/javascript' src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div id="sidebar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-default affix">
                        <li><a href="#correct">Correct</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#incorrect">Incorrect</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#omission">Omission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#premature">Premature</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="mycontent" class="col-md-10" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidebar">

                    <div id="correct" class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Correct responses</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">        
                            <h4>Graphic</h4>
                                <img src="/graph/group/post-op/lineerror/12/correct" onerror="imgError(this);"> 
                             <h4>Table</h4> 
                               Table here 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="incorrect" class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Incorrect responses</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">        
                            <h4>Graphic</h4>
                                <img src="/graph/group/post-op/lineerror/12/incorrect" onerror="imgError(this);"> 
                             <h4>Table</h4> 
                               Table here 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="omission" class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Omission responses</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">        
                            <h4>Graphic</h4>
                                <img src="/graph/group/post-op/lineerror/12/omission" onerror="imgError(this);"> 
                             <h4>Table</h4> 
                               Table here 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="premature" class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Premature responses</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">        
                            <h4>Graphic</h4>
                                <img src="/graph/group/post-op/lineerror/12/premature" onerror="imgError(this);"> 
                             <h4>Table</h4> 
                               Table here 
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

My links and my affix are working properly but I can't see the scrollspy.

See the adapted [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/J3bDZ/5/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "To easily add scrollspy behavior to your topbar navigation, add `data-spy="scroll"` to the element you want to spy on (most typically this would be the `<body>`). Then add the `data-target` attribute with the ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap `.nav` component." -- [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).

Those `data-` attributes must be added to whichever element is being scrolled. Unless `#mycontent` is `overflow:scroll`, you need to add those `data-` attributes to your `<body>` tag instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/qKFqg/

Comment: I added `overflow:scroll` to `#mycontent` but it still doesn't work. See http://jsfiddle.net/J3bDZ/6

Comment: It works fine, if you add a `height` to `#mycontent` to that it's scrollable. You also need to specify styles for the `active` element. (In your fiddle, jQuery was loaded after Bootstrap, so nothing would have worked.) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/qKFqg/)